# Do any JavaScript libraries support ISO8601 recurring intervals?

Tags: javascript, date, standards, iso8601, recurring-events

I'd like to publish data with recurring intervals (eg, "every second Tuesday starting from date ....-..-.."), primarily for use by web developers. I had assumed that using a standard, ISO 8601, would make the data easy to work with.

But - are there actually any libraries that can parse ISO 8601 dates with recurring intervals? For example: `R/2015-01-14/P2W`

Javascript's native `Date` object fails:

```
 Date.parse('R/2015-01-14/P2W')
 NaN
```

[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) fails:

```
> moment('R/2015-01-14/P2W');
{ [Number: NaN]
....
  _d: Invalid Date }
```

So, is there any support out there for recurring intervals (specifically, the `R/.../PxW` format above) that I haven't found?

Comment: I'm not aware of a lib that can do this right now. Maybe you should try to use this: [iso8601-durations.js](https://gist.github.com/jmrocela/7167208) and open a issue here [moment-recur](https://github.com/c-trimm/moment-recur) - because this one is officially reference on the moment.js site - with the suggestion to include it.

Comment: Good suggestion, I've opened an issue.